# Convert wstring to WS_STRING

Tags: visual-c++, wwsapi

What is the best way to convert wstring to WS_STRING?

Trying with macros:

```
wstring d=L"ddd";
WS_STRING url = WS_STRING_VALUE(d.c_str()) ;
```

And have error:

```
cannot convert from 'const wchar_t *' to 'WCHAR *'
```

Comment: You can probably `const_cast<>` yourself out of trouble.  Depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

```
WS_STRING url = {};
url.length = d.length();
WsAlloc(heap, sizeof(WCHAR) * url.length, (void**)&url.chars, error);
memcpy(url.chars, d.c_str(), sizeof(WCHAR) * url.length); // Don't want a null terminator
```

**Long answer:**

Don't use `WS_STRING_VALUE` on anything other than a `WCHAR[]`.  You can get it to compile using `const_cast<>` but you will run into two issues:

1. The `WS_STRING` will have an incorrect `length` member due to the macro's use of `RTL_NUMBER_OF` instead of looking for null termination.
2. The `WS_STRING` will just reference `d` - it will not take a copy.  This is obviously problematic if it's a local variable.

The relevant code snippets:

```
//  Utilities structure
//  
//   An array of unicode characters and a length.
//  
struct _WS_STRING {
    ULONG length;
    _Field_size_(length) WCHAR* chars;
};

//  Utilities macro
//  
//   A macro to initialize a WS_STRING structure given a constant string.
//  
#define WS_STRING_VALUE(S) { WsCountOf(S) - 1, S }

//  Utilities macro
//  
//   Returns the number of elements of an array.
//  
#define WsCountOf(arrayValue) RTL_NUMBER_OF(arrayValue)
```