# Converting UINT to WS_STRING

Tags: c++, wcf, int, const-cast

I'm writing a response to a WCF call in unmanaged code. The problem is that I have an integer which I want to convert into `WS_STRING` and respond back.

The `std::towstring` converts only to a wstring and doesn't convert into WS_STRING. How can I make that happen ?

I saw there was an older thread that had a similar question, but it seemed unanswered.

```
int i = 100;
responseWsString = std::to_wstring(i);
//Throws compiler error : No operator '=' matches operands of type WS_STRING = std::wstring
```

This is expected as the types are differnt. The other thread mentions that `const_cast<>` is not a good approach. Then how do I solve this simple problem to convert int into WS_STRING ?

Here is a link to the previous: 
[Convert wstring to WS_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354653/convert-wstring-to-ws-string)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27975754/7571258) already shows how to convert a `std::wstring` into a `WS_STRING`.

You already know how to convert a number into `std::wstring`:

```
int i = 100;
std::wstring iStr = std::to_wstring(i);
```

So it's just a matter of using the `iStr` as input for the solution provided in the linked answer.

Hint: Replace `d` by `iStr`, replace `url` by `responseWsString`.